# Trapping Permission Error when opening workbook with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, ioerror, permissionerror

I have an application that interacts with xlsx workbooks using openpyxl. It is possible for users to have the needed workbook open in Excel when the program runs, throwing a FilePermission Error. There seem to be two issues

(ISSUE 1) the following:

```
try:
    wbTarget    = load_workbook(filename='%s' % (strfileTarget))
except PermissionError:
    print("Please close the file")
    break
```

throws a "SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop" error. This is weird given the same pattern is used in other situations (such as trapping'None' during xlsx processing) without problem. So the question for this issue is, Can someone please explain why the break is not working here?

(ISSUE 2) Instead of the break, the 'print' line below would be substituted for a tk.messagebox.showerror to tell the user to close the file and then continue or quit the program, but... i have to catch the exception first, so here is what i tried:

```
try:
    wbTarget    = load_workbook(filename='%s' % (strfileTarget))
except PermissionError:
    print("Please close the file")
```

this does not trap the "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:" error. From research it also appears the exception might be an 'IOError'. Changing to 'IOError' still throws the same error instead of trapping it.

finally, i just tried to catch 'any ol' exception with 'exception:' and omitting the exception type. but error is still not trapped when the program is run.

```
try:
    wbTarget    = load_workbook(filename='%s' % (strfileTarget))
except:
    print("Please close the file")
```

So the question for this issue is, how is the file permission issue trapped?

Comment: What are you trying to break? Is your try except inside a for or while loop?

Comment: I was unable to replicate your issue with catching a `PermissionError`. Can you provide a [mre] that produces the error

Comment: By removing all permissions on an xlsx file I was able to replicate "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:" error. The error was then able to be captured correctly by the exception 'except PermissionError' as you have written it. Python 3.8, Openpyxl 0.26.x

Comment: Could not replicate same error when 2 separate users open the same xl file across network using Excel and python.

Comment: @jezza_99. Yes! thanks. the break was failing because the test was not in a loop but inside a subroutine only. 'return' is the best option to have the program gracefully fail and alert the user to the problem before proceeding.

Comment: @mokan, 'removing all permissions'. I have no permissions set when trying to open the file as can be seen. Do you mean i need to not 'be lazy' and add  "read_only=False, keep_vba=True, data_only=True, keep_links=True"? as shown here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.reader.excel.html

Comment: @cornhenge yes definitely return is the better option. To further explain my comment, I was able to get a `PermissionError` with an excel file open and then catch it using an `except PermissionError` line. Can you please provide the full error traceback?

Comment: @cornhenge no, I was just attempting to simulate a permissions denied error to confirm the try/except would catch it.